# How to trigger autocomplete suggestion box in vim or neovim (Plugin neoclide/coc.vim)

Tags: vim, autocomplete, vim-plugin

I'm Neovim user

and I use Plugin [neoclide/coc.vim](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) for autocompletion

but when my cursor focus out, I can not get suggestion box again

(How can I call this box? suggest box or hint box? I want to know this box name)

I want to trigger it and see again, Is there any command or variable for this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've commented in https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/issues/2299#issuecomment-686293001

> The suggestion box in your image is signatureHelp. If you want to reopen it, you need to trigger `triggerCharacters` in your function, usually is `(` and `,`. The triggerCharacters is defined by LS.

Comment: thanks for making window term clear , I’m curious the meaning of LS,  is it person name?

Comment: LS means language server.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, the answer is on the front page of CoC's [github project](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim). You need to map something to coc#refresh(). For instance, to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to trigger completion, you need to put the following in your vimrc:

```
inoremap <silent><expr> <c-space> coc#refresh()
```

There are more examples on the project's page.

Comment: I think this answer is for autocomplete, my question is about suggestion box in above picture,

Comment: Perhaps you are referring to show documentation? From coc README: "Use K to show documentation in preview window."
`nnoremap <silent> K :call <SID>show_documentation()<CR>`

Answer (score 7):

> TLDR: try this <kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>@</kbd></kbd>

I found this in README of [neoclide/coc.nvim](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim):

```
" Use <c-space> to trigger completion.
if has('nvim')
  inoremap <silent><expr> <c-space> coc#refresh()
else
  inoremap <silent><expr> <c-@> coc#refresh()
endif
```

The weirdness here is that, <kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd></kbd> is not working, despite using **neovim** NOT **vim**.

But there is a good trick to get your desired key binding as it appears from your terminal emulator point of view:

1. Enter `insert` mode
2. Press <kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd></kbd>
3. Then press your keys you want to bind, <kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd></kbd>

**Ops!** nothing is inserted in my case. It seems that my terminal doesn't recognize using Ctrl and Space or understands this keybinding differently and intercepts it. So this is the real problem!

Things I tried to solve the problem:

1. I changed the default coc config a little bit:

   ```
   inoremap <silent><expr> <c-space> coc#refresh()
   inoremap <silent><expr> <c-@> coc#refresh()
   ```
2. I tried **bash** as I was using **zsh** as a shell, but the problem is still there.
3. Then I tried another terminal emulator and the problem is solved, alhamdulillah.

Comment: Ctrl + @ works as well. Thanks bro.

Answer (score 4):

To Browse from suggestion box:

```
- <Tab > 

- <Ctrl - x> <Ctrl -f>

- <Ctrl - p ><Ctrl -n>

- <Ctrl - n ><Ctrl -n>
```

To Confirm selection

```
- <Ctrl - y>
```